# Create folder in Bucket(Personal Hub) in Autodesk Forge Data Management

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk, forge

Can We Create folder in Bucket(Personal Hub) in Autodesk Forge Data Management,Just like we get in BIM 360 (Enterprise Account)

Comment: It looks like the answer below helped with your question. Do you know how to accept answers here?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can create folders in Personal Hubs (BIM 360 Team, Fusion Team) Here is the endpoint to the API call in order to create it.

https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/projects-project_id-folders-POST/

Just make sure you are not confusing Buckets with Hubs. Buckets are containers where model translations are stored using the Model Derivative API, Hubs are the ones you have access with the use of the Data Management API.

Comment: The above mention link for folder creation for enterprise account not personal account right?

Comment: Actually I m talking about https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/tutorials/prepare-file-for-viewer/ can we create a folder here

Comment: Ok, Folders cannot be created inside of Buckets, the buckets are use as containers as part of our Object Storage Space. Maybe try explaining a bit more in detail what are you trying to achieve? Also in regards to the other question. The link I provided not necessarily needs an enterprise account. This is just targeting a different approach to the storage of your files using the Data Management API, which lets you have your files in Autodesk Team services, BIM 360 Docs or 3rd party file storage systems such as Google Drive, Dropbox, Box... Hope this makes more sense now.

Comment: Thanks Sir for your valuable feedback

Comment: Carol, if you have no longer questions and I have solved all your doubts, please go ahead and mark the last comment as a solution so we can make this a closed case. Thank you very much.